# All permutations of a column

Tags: sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008

I have a number of questions q, each of which can have several answers a.

```
declare @table table (
  q tinyint,
  a tinyint
)

insert into @table values (1,1),
                          (1,2),
                          (2,1),
                          (3,1),
                          (3,2),
                          (3,3)
```

Is there a query that will bring back all the permutations of answers for a set of questions?

For example, if the set of questions is 1 and 3, then I need all the permutations of how questions 1 and 3 can be answered together. The first question (question 1) can be answered two ways, and the second question (question 3) can be answered three ways. Thus, the result set would be (the first column just groups the sets of answers):

```
s1,1,1
s1,3,1

s2,1,1
s2,3,2

s3,1,1
s3,3,3

s4,1,2
s4,3,1

s5,1,2
s5,3,2

s6,1,2
s6,3,3
```

The input list of questions is dynamic, i.e. it could be any subset of the entire list of questions.  The number of questions and the number of answers for each question are also dynamic, i.e. unknown ahead of time.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand where the results come from. "if the set of q's is 1 and 2" means the first 4 rows. Not 5 as you show. Where does g1 and g2 come from? It's a group, yes, but what is the rule?

Comment: When you post a question best to stick around to answer this kind of request for clarification. I have no clue where you derive your expected results from either and suspect they are probably incorrect.

Comment: The question is all the permutations of c for a given set of q's. To keep it simple (removing the multiple rows for a given q/c combination), if I have 1,1; 1,2; 2,1; 2,2; 2,3, I want all unique combinations of the second column for the set of first columns. Thus, the sets would be 1,1/2,1; 1,1/2,2; 1,1/2,3; 1,2/2,1; 1,2/2,2; 1,2/2,3.

Comment: So that's a `CROSS JOIN`. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/4726) but a cross join doesn't give you the desired results in the question for the example data.

Comment: Right, I've worked along the same lines, with the same incorrect results so far.

Comment: So are the desired results in the question wrong? If not edit the question to explain exactly how they are derived.

Comment: No, the desired results are not wrong. I've tried to simplify the question by eliminating the third column (I can deal with that in another query once the first one is solved), and expanding on the explanation of what I mean by the permutation of the answers.

Comment: Are you storing all the possible answers to each question anywhere in the database? If so, the question is relatively simple. If not, how do you expect to get the answer out of a database if it's not stored in the database in the first place?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. @table has all of the question/answer combination possibilities.